# Where was the main character in Outlander from?

Tags: movie, outlander

The main character from Outlander was clearly from a futuristic society, but he also ended up in early medieval Norway. His computer system was clearly aware of earth and its culture since it knew what language to upload to his mind. Was he from a society that was simply aware of earth and its inhabitants or did he undergo some sort of time travel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I am sorry to say the main character in Outland, the alien Kainan played by Jim Caviezel is unfortunately, NOT a time traveler (which would make far more sense) but is supposedly a very human-looking member of an alien race. We are given little information about where he comes from, why he looks like us, and what he was doing on Earth besides transporting the Moorwen.**

He does seem to know quite a bit about Earth, and even knows enough to not tell us he is an alien. He tells about a dragon, instead. Despite it's science-fiction theme, the movie was really a fantasy yarn with sci-fi trappings. They wanted to avoid doing a direct retelling of Grendel (even though it ends up really feeling like the same story, anyway) so they made Kainan an alien. But this is really a human story, so no real effort was made to promote Kainan's alien nature.

If it makes you feel any better, almost everyone agrees with you, that by 2008, when the movie was made, there is no reason we would expect an alien from another planet to look exactly like us, without the use of technology.

The movie is supposedly based on a Viking legend where the gods send their servant to help the Vikings kill a dragon that escapes from the god's realm. The hero, upon slaying the dragon, instead of returning from whence he came, decides to stay and become the king. Sorry to say, the best thing about this movie is the legend it's derived from.

[image: Moorwen, alien dragon]

*Concept art for the Moorwen, the alien Kainan was chasing, last of its kind. At least IT looked alien...*

Comment: Good answer! He should've been a time traveller. :)

Comment: @Thaddeus: Dude I think we saw different movies! Other than "a big beasty" I don't see a Beowulf & Grendel parallel. Also it was clearly stated that earth was a former colony of Kainan's people, thus glossing over the whole humanoid alien question, all be it quite ineffectively (leaves little questions regarding fossil records etc), but which is sufficient for the narrative integrity for the story. I thoroughly enjoyed it for what it was, a B-Movie juxtaposing two popular genres. The Morwen Beasty was beautifully rendered too IMHO :)

Comment: It was not the worst movie ever made or anything like that. (I did enjoy it as B movie fare) I just felt they could have made a bit of a better effort to rationalize how WE came to be living on Earth as an outpost of an advance civilization (without technology) with an existence in the fossil record (as you mentioned) as well as any other inconsistencies that cropped up. Yes, I loved the renderings of the Moorwen. I just couldn't find any online to share.

Answer (score 4):

It's given in the film that Earth is home to a lost colony of Kainan's people, extrapolating that, earth "people" aren't from earth or Vikings aren't from earth (which raises questions about the fossil record, or about human/alien physiology.

That Earth was in his Database allowed him to "download" the local language, give him knowledge of mythical creatures such as dragons etc etc

His race was aware of earth, there is no suggestion of time travel in the movie.

Comment: Are you referring to the scene when he asks the computer where he was? So, "Abandoned Seed Colony" was referring to the entire planet, not his location in Europe? I never made that connection. Very interesting.

Comment: @Ryan: I raise it as a possibility. However it raises other questions, if it was abandoned long enough for individual languages to spring up, how could the computer "teach" him the correct language? Best not to ask how the roller-coaster works, best to just enjoy the ride, or so I find :)

Comment: If you have magical FTL technology, what prevents you from leaving a few probes all over the place, invisible and collecting data? Certainly the hardware's cheap enough, so as long as you have the bandwidth...

Comment: @JohnO Magical FTLs are so much better than regular FTLs :)

Answer (score 0):

Kainan people know Earth as he mentions Earth as an outpost. Plus he mentions that he was bringing back the bodies for burial and that's when the Moorwen got on his space-craft. There is also logic in the movie that in the future we humans will be capturing land from other planets. How else do you think we discovere there is oxygen on Mars?